# Maven stuck on old version of system dependency

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies

My Maven project has a dependency on a non-Maven library, which is coded as a system dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>${foo.version}</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${foo.jar}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

where the location of the library can be controlled via local properties:

```
<properties>
  <foo.version>2.1.1</foo.version>
  <foo.basedir>/usr/local</foo.basedir>
  <foo.libdir>${foo.basedir}/lib</foo.libdir>
  <foo.jar>${foo.basedir}/java/foo-${foo.version}.jar</foo.jar>
</properties>
```

Recently, the library switched from version 2.1.1 to version 2.2.0, so I changed the `foo.version` property, but Maven seems to be stuck on the old version:

```
...
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.example:foo:jar:2.1.1
...
```

I have run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` (many times, actually). The string `2.1.1` does not appear anywhere in my POM, `profiles.xml`, or `settings.xml`. Still, every time I try to build my project, Maven fails with the above error.

What's going on here? Where is Maven storing the dependency version information and how can I update it?

Comment: First question: by local properties, you mean in the pom.xml, don't you? Second (stupid) question: why don't you add the foo JAR into your local repository (your current setup isn't portable anyway).

Comment: Yes, the properties are defined in a profile in the POM. I could add the JAR to the local repository, but it's a JNI binding for a native library, so I still need to resolve the local properties to set up the linker options. If `foo.version` is stuck at 2.1.1, the native library won't link.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `${foo.version}` might be getting resolved as a filter property. Can you check the properties file under `src/main/filters`.

Not sure if this is indeed the problem but just give it a try and update back.

The other reason that I could think of is - there might be a transitive dependency on `com.example:foo:jar:2.1.1`. That is some other dependency which needs 2.1.1 version of this artifact. You can find which artifact is bringing this transitively by doing `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Nope. There is no src/main/filters.

Comment: Check the edits.. I think `mvn dependency:tree` might help you zero in on the artifact bringing 2.1.1

Comment: Actually `mvn dependency:tree` fails because of the "missing" dependency.

Comment: Chris, just to troubleshoot we need to figure it out who is bringing this jar to your project. So, I would suggest point everything to the old set up of 2.1.1 and try to get the `mvn dependency:tree` running (u may need to install some old dummy jar as 2.1.1 to local repo). As then we will get clear idea which artifact has dependency on 2.1.1.

Comment: I'll be damned. I copied `foo-2.2.0.jar` to `foo-2.1.1.jar` and ran `mvn dependency:tree`. It returned the resolved dependency `com.example:foo:2.2.0:system`. I deleted `foo-2.1.1.jar`. No more dependency failure. If you want to write this up as a workaround, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You know what.  Seeing the workaround that @Chris Conway found, I think that this might have been "solved" by simply running `mvn clean`.

And even if it would not have helped here, it is always worth trying `mvn clean` when something strange happens.

Comment: I ran `mvn clean` about a million times.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency version conflict is a very common problem and most of the time when we start building our application, we never focus or generally we forgot on that aspect until and unless our application starts behaving in an unexpected way or getting started some exception.

For readers and visitors of SO who are interested in knowing the reason why dependency conflicts arises and how we can avoid them in our application , I found a source here explained in a  precise way ,so i thought of adding my 2 bits to it .

http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/

Cheers

Comment: URL to your post is broken.

Comment: For "Why Maven chose the older version jar when I have latest version of same jar available?"